# How to convert Ienumerable<system.web.mvc.selectedlistitem> to Generic.List<system.web.mvc.selecteditemlist>?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

> Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collection.Generic.Ienumerable<system.web.mvc.selectedlistitem>'
> to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<system.web.mvc.selecteditemlist>'

I am trying to make a selectedlistitem for View model to make a dropdownmenu.

ViewModel of SurveyResult

```
public List<SelectListItem> SurveyMasterList { get; set; }
```

MasterList takes value from database

```
var MasterList = _mcniDbContext.SurveyMaster.Where(e => e.SurveyMasterId == tempCustomer.SurveyMasterId).ToList();
```

The error comes at the code below.

```
temp.SurveyMasterList = MasterList.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text = m.SurveyName, Value = m.SurveyMasterId.ToString() });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that temp.SurveyMasterList is List of SelectListItem too, just fix your second query by adding ToList();

```
temp.SurveyMasterList = MasterList
.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text = m.SurveyName, Value = m.SurveyMasterId.ToString() })
.ToList();
```

but it is better to merge both queries

```
temp.SurveyMasterList = _mcniDbContext.SurveyMaster
.Where(e => e.SurveyMasterId == tempCustomer.SurveyMasterId)
.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text = m.SurveyName, Value = m.SurveyMasterId.ToString() })
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your `List<SelectListItem>` as `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in your view model. Then in your controller fill it like this :

```
viewmodelobject.SurveyMasterList = new SelectList(_mcniDbContext.SurveyMaster, "SurveyMasterId", "SurveyName");
```

In your View, you can use it like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DrpSurvey", Model.SurveyMasterList , "Master List: ", new { @class = "form-control" })
```